# Superuser (stack exchange) links open in the same window

Tags: discussion

I'm using Google Chrome with Windows 7. Everything a link is clicked on superuser site, the target webpage opens in the current tab instead of opening in a new tab. Is this a site related behavior? Because clicking links on Facebook opens in new tab. 
I don't know the terminology for this type of behavior. I googled but could not find a simple answer or setting. 
Holding the 'ctrl' key helps but I think there should be a correct way to make it work

Comment: This is based on the html markup of the <a> href tag.  Your ctrl+click workaround is the best alternative to asking SE to rewrite every link to include the target="_blank" attribute.  You can verify by right clicking any link on any page and choosing "Inspect Element" (in Chrome) then comparing the elements & attributes.

Comment: I think this question is about the user trying to configure his browser in order for his links to open in another tab / window. Which seems like a computer question to me. I don't know why people think that this should be closed because this is off-topic. If you choose to close a question - please leave a comment

Answer (score 2):

### Press control while you click to open in a new tab.

That is is the easiest solution, the other way is to install **Tampermonkey**, and use [this](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_openInTab) script which will open all the links in new tabs. But I don't recommend you to do that because not all the websites allow to open links in new tabs.

Comment: @G-Man, yes but that is too much work for the OP /s

Comment: Middle-click also works if your mouse has a scroll-wheel

Answer (score 2):

The setting you are looking for would be in the web site itself. If a link in a site (this one for example) is not set to open in a separate tab it will not do that unless you hold CTRL while you click, or you could also right-click on the link to see the context menu and then specify to open in a new tab.

Comment: Do you have two accounts?

Comment: No just one, but I am listed on multiple stack exchange sites.